# Detect Image Saliency Bounding Box / Potential Train on custom data

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, object-detection

The "focus area" is defined as the area (bounding box) of an image that contains subject matter of an image. It can be anything like people, cars, plant, art etc.

Currently this area is selected by a human. Given a large (? 50K Images) dataset with these bounding boxes, would it be feasible to train some kind image recognition model that would automatically select a bounding box in a similar manner?

I've did some research in regard to object detection and image segmentation but both tasks seem very different from what I'm trying to achieve. My totally naive approach would be to train a object detection model with a single class "focus area". But I can't assess if this is the right approach and I failed to find any information in regards to such a problem.

If this approach is feasible, what would be the state of the art to implement this in regard to frameworks/models/architecture.

Or are there better approaches/models to achieve this sort of task?

**Edit**

As pointed out in the comments I’m looking for „saliency“. So let me rephrase:

- What are good tools/frameworks (preferably oss) to detect the saliency as a bounding box
- I found a few papers regarding this topic in regards to deeplerning but did not found any good implementation. Is there anything what you can recommend?

Comment: ah, you don't care about "focus". you care about what someone's gaze would be drawn to. we call that "saliency". tons of algorithms. -- as always, best results come from AI/ML. -- note that you're asking for recommendations.

Comment: Thanks! I checked it. It seems indeed like what I‘m looking for. I updated the question accordingly. Any recommendations?